# cls files could not be loaded inside VB project

Tags: vb6

I am facing an issue while opening an existing VB project. It says 'c:...\test.cls' could not be loaded even though the file is present in the given location. Similarly it throws the same error for .ctl and frm files as well. I am not an expert user of VB (6.0). Can some one throw some light on this. In which case .vbp will not be able to load .cls files that are present in the given locations

Thanks

Comment: Is that the complete error message? Doesn't it say **why** it can't be loaded?

Comment: yes. it does not say why it can't be loaded

Comment: But if I create a new cls file and copy the content from the files that are already existing, they could be loaded.

Comment: I could find out the reason. Our code versioning system was having different line ending settings. 
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Late answer (7 years later), but had this problem. The reason for this could be due to different line endings depending on your source control provider. I was using Git (hosted by bitbucket) and checkout was done via Teamcity.

Solution was to enable "Convert line-endings to CRLF" in the VCS Root settings for the problematic project.